# how to ingest non-one-minute data in zipline

Tags: python, zipline

when I try to ingest data into zipline bundles, since I could not get one-minute data, and only have 5-minutes klines data. Looks like standard zipline does not support it? 
cited from http://www.zipline.io/bundles.html

ingest(environ,
       asset_db_writer,
       minute_bar_writer,
       daily_bar_writer,
       adjustment_writer,
       calendar,
       start_session,
       end_session,
       cache,
       show_progress,
       output_dir)

minute_bar_writer
minute_bar_writer is an instance of BcolzMinuteBarWriter. This writer is used to convert data to zipline’s internal bcolz format to later be read by a BcolzMinuteBarReader. If minute data is provided, users should call write() with an iterable of (sid, dataframe) tuples. The show_progress argument should also be forwarded to this method. If the data source does not provide minute level data, then there is no need to call the write method. It is also acceptable to pass an empty iterator to write() to signal that there is no minutely data.

Anyway, I use this interface to ingest the 5 minutes klines into zipline. but when I call run_algorithm, whatever the data_frequency I input, it prompt errors.

```
data = run_algorithm(start=start,
                     end=end,
                     initialize=initialize,
                     capital_base=100000,
                     handle_data=handle_data,
                     bundle="poloniex_csv",
                     data_frequency='60min',
                     trading_calendar=PoloniexExchangeCalendar())
```

AssertionError: All readers must share target trading_calendar. Reader= for type= uses calendar= which does not match the desired shared calendar=

How to fix this issue? for instance let BcolzMinuteBarReader support 5minutes data. I am ok with deal the 5 minutes data in zipline handle_data functions.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that one shouldn't use the calendar class directly, `PoloniexExchangeCalendar()` here, but they should invoke `get_calendar(calendar_name)` to get an instance of the calendar from the calendar  factory instead. In theory, this would guarantee that there is only one instance of the calendar used by the framework and therefore the line

```
assert trading_calendar == r.trading_calendar
```

in the dispatch_bar_reader.py would always resolve to true. In my case and for some reason, even when using `get_calendar(calendar_name)` wasn't exactly sufficient and I was getting a comparison of two different instances of the same calendar class which inevitably resolved to `False`. Hence I was getting the same error. I went around the issue by having my calendar class implementing its own equality comparison by adding the following lines inside the custom calendar class

```
__hash__ = ExchangeCalendar.__hash__

def __eq__(self, other):
    return all(self.all_sessions == other.all_sessions) if isinstance(other, CoinbaseExchangeCalendar) else False
```

This did the trick for me by bypassing the technicalities of comparing the two instances but admittedly without actually ever figuring out why `get_calendar(cal_name)` didn't return the singleton instance of the custom calendar class.